# Webfocus reports in datawarehousing

Tags: data-warehouse, webfocus

I have below requirement:
In webfocus version8,  if i enter any value in webfocus REPORT search box then in the table and row having that value should be highlighted. please suggest how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

```
-DEFAULT &SEARCHTERM = 'JAPAN'
TABLE FILE CAR
BY COUNTRY
BY MODEL
ON TABLE SET PAGE-NUM NOLEAD
ON TABLE NOTOTAL
ON TABLE PCHOLD FORMAT HTML
ON TABLE SET HTMLCSS ON
ON TABLE SET STYLE *
 INCLUDE = endeflt,
 WRAP=OFF,
$
 DEFMACRO=COND0001,
 MACTYPE=RULE,
 WHEN=N1 EQ '&SEARCHTERM',
$
TYPE=DATA,
 BACKCOLOR=RGB(139 0 102),
 COLOR='WHITE',
 MACRO=COND0001,
$
TYPE=TABHEADING,
 FONT='TAHOMA',
 STYLE=BOLD,
 JUSTIFY=LEFT,
$
ENDSTYLE
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Active HTML format type as the AHTML capabilities will already take care of this for you and then some.

Just change ON TABLE PCHOLD FORMAT HTML to 
ON TABLE PCHOLD FORMAT AHTML.

The way that you have your program written now, the search term is only defined in a macro, but not implemented anywhere.  In addition, since the search term is based on a variable, it would need to be known before the report is run, which I don't think is the desired outcome.